# Insert into nested table plsql

Tags: oracle, plsql, sql-insert, nested-table

I'm a newbie with pl sql and I'm facing some problems with inserting into nested tables (I'm using these just to test a procedure).
So my code is:

```
insert into t_prenotazioni
      (nro_cliente, data_disponibilita)
    values
      (righe.nro_cliente, v_data_disponibilita);
```

where t_prenotazioni is a table of a type defined by me, righe.nro_cliente is a value that I get from a cursor and v_data_disponibilita is a variable.
The error that I get is:

> PLS-00330 invalid use of type name or subtype

Comment: You can INSERT INTO a table, not a variable. If you need to populate a variable you need an assignment or some kinf of SELECT ... INTO.... FROM ...Please try to better explain what you're trying to do to get some help.

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to declare a nested table and I did it like this:   " type prenotazioni is table of type_prenotazioni;
  t_prenotazioni prenotazioni;". Then I'm trying to insert into this table, the type of the table has 2 fields.

Comment: @editLxo You have to use this in a PL./SQL block

Comment: A simplified [test case](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing the definition of the table and the types would help here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably trying to do something like:

```
declare
    type type_prenotazioni is record(nro_cliente number, data_disponibilita date);
    type prenotazioni is table of type_prenotazioni;
    vPrenotazioni prenotazioni;
begin
    vPrenotazioni := new prenotazioni();
    vPrenotazioni.extend(1);
    vPrenotazioni(1).nro_cliente := 10;
    vPrenotazioni(1).data_disponibilita := sysdate;
    --
    for i in vPrenotazioni.first .. vPrenotazioni.last loop
        dbms_output.put_line(vPrenotazioni(i).nro_cliente || ' - ' ||
                                to_char(vPrenotazioni(i).data_disponibilita, 'dd/mm/yyyy')
                               );
    end loop;
end;
```

I would stronlgy recommend having a look at [the Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/LNPLS/plsql-collections-and-records.htm#LNPLS005) to improve your knowledge; this is only a simple, small example, but there are many many different things you may want to do.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. My only question now is when you do vPrenotazioni.extend(1), at the next insertion (because I'm inserting not only 1 value in the table but multiple) the value that was inside the table is overwritten?

Comment: Here I extend to insert a single value; if you need to insert more than one record, you need to extend accordingly and then use vPrenotazioni(i) where i is your number. Or, you may want to have a look at SELECT ... BULK COLLECT INTO .... Have a look at some BULK COLLECT examples to learn a way to massively populate your structures